# Single table design in mongodb and its impact on pricing

Tags: mongodb

Our client wanted to design Mongodb schema in a single table design model similar to how we'd in AWS Dynamodb, with generic index keys and its values prefixed by the type of entity. That would allow us to consolidate all types of entities into one collection. The reason he quoted was that multiple collections would mean queries on multiple collections which would increase the cost.

Is that true? Does multiple collections increase the cost compared to a single collections? Does the pricing model change according to hosting it in mongodb cloud vs your own ec2 instance? Also is that a recommended schema design for mongodb? Cause it's definitely the recommended design pattern for dynamodb but I couldn't find anything on the internet about single table design in mongodb.